# Getting weird python error when I run a simple django script in Eclipse, not happening in console

Tags: python, django, eclipse, django-models, eclipse-plugin

I am running a basic script that sets up the django environment by itself, to enable me to test the ORM features of django without having to implement web pages. The script then imports one of the types defined in my models. This error doesn't happen when I run this script from iPython, only from eclipse. Simply doing this import causes a weird exception like the following:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_exc'" in <bound method Signal._remove_receiver of <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x026802B0>> ignored
```

My script is as follows:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from stats.models import Person

for p in Person.objects.all():
     print p.Name
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Probably this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue23003

Answer (score 3):

After importing an existing Django project in Eclipse I had the same AttributeError

I just removed the *.pyc files... and it works... !?

- right click on project ->pyDev -> remove *.pyc, *.pyo, ...

Answer (score 2):

After some judicious googling, I'd say that Eclipse is causing the problem and that it may be hard to trace. `print_exc` is a function in Python's traceback module. Eclipse may be trying to show you a traceback, failing, and eating the result in the process.

I think a reasonable workaround would be to continue work on this script in a tool that doesn't present you with inscrutable errors. You may find an actual (fixable) error in your code, or you may find that Eclipse was raising a false alarm due to a bug in its Python integration.

If at that point you're unsure whether there is a problem with your code, adding some tests might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that eclipse is using a different version of the python interpreter?

Comment: There's only one on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give more details, such as the Person model.

Without seeing that I would guess the model attribute is meant to be in lowercase (ie p.name)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it, because it's printing out the names of all the Person objects, and after completing it throws that exception.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see, you do not havbe any problem with importing your modules. Try this to check if everything you need is ready for you. Probably that would not be the reason of your problem but better you check it too

iPuthon imports django system path automatically, so what you need is alresdy ready under your hands.

```
import sys
sys.path
```

check this out to see if all you need is there when you run it from eclipse, fiff with ipython result...